# Distorted border for UITableViewCell in a grouped UITableView (Retina size)

Tags: ios5, uitableview, ios4, cell

I created two custom UITableViewCells and put them in a grouped UITableView. Testing to see how these cells look on non retina sceen everything look fine, but on retina i get a weird effect for these cell. What's the problem and how to solve it ?

[image]

Comment: Are you calling [super layoutSubviews]; in your cells?

Comment: no, i'm not. can you tell why should i call it ?

Comment: So, in my case, the cell drawing crashed (e.g. missing lines) when I subclassed a UITableViewCell without calling [super layoutSubviews]; in my own implementation of layoutSubviews. :-)

Comment: i'm not subclassing , i just create in same xib , two tableviewcells and connect to view controller using outlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `separatorColor` property of my `UITableView`. I use `colorWithPatternImage:` to set a custom separator from an image that was bigger in size dimensions than my cell (320 pixels vs 280 pixels).
I scaled down image, and now it works fine :)